# How to add .html JQuery before element

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm quite new with JQ thing, so I do not understand why `.html` works, and `.before` does not but I hope someone will help. I'm using it within some old ASP project, so this code is within `.ascx` file.

I use this line:

```
$('#UploadSummaryFile1').html($(this).val()+'<span id="DeleteCrossFile1" onclick="DeleteElement(1);"><img src="Images/DeleteCross.png" alt="Delete"></span>');
```

And it works fine, I get image after the "UploadSummaryFile1" container. So I have on the screen |FilenameX|, and I need to have |X Filename|.

I tried changing `.html` to `.before` but apparently that's not the way how to use it.

Comment: have you looked at [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) ? `.html()` will replace all the content in the target.

Comment: Nope, just .before and .insertBefore... will check, tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#UploadSummaryFile1').html(
    '<span id="DeleteCrossFile1" onclick="DeleteElement(1);"><img src="Images/DeleteCross.png" alt="Delete"></span>'
    + $(this).val()
);
```

So, basically, switch `$(this).val()` and the rest of the html around.

Or better yet:

```
$('#UploadSummaryFile1').prepend('<span id="DeleteCrossFile1" onclick="DeleteElement(1);"><img src="Images/DeleteCross.png" alt="Delete"></span>');
```